# Sequence between PolyA signal and PolyA tail

Tags: rna, transcription

Between the polyadenylation (PolyA) signal (AAUAAA in humans) and the start of the polyA tail, there is a short sequence of about 10~20 (G/U rich) bases, is there a special term for it?

[image]

Image credit: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3175714/

Comment: Does this region have any regulatory effect? When artificial mRNAs are made, the polyA tail is often just stuck to the end of the stop codon, omitting the polyA signal and this intervening sequence. The mRNA still works to produce protein, but could this sequence affect the amount of protein or duration of expression?

Comment: My guess is that the GU rich region helps to keep the pre mRNA in place before endonuclolytic cleavage occurs.

Comment: I am not aware of a particular term other than more generally referring to the sequence between the stop codon and the polyA tail as the 3'-UTR.